# Sum inside groupby python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pandas-groupby

I created a series as follows:

```
pop_by_state = population.groupby(states)
```

Where population and states were series of the same size, but there were three (different) populations for each (repeated) state. When I print pop_by_state I get a table with each of the three populations in the second column associated with each state in the first(one "cell" state to three "cells" populations).

Now I would like to sum this three values for each state and get a series with the total population for each state.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Hi! Could you share your data? Try `df.to_clipboard()`

Comment: Here is te link in wich I'm working:
https://fzigxiwzncaghzpexaginp.coursera-apps.org/notebooks/Assignment%202.ipynb

I'm trying to solve problem 6.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you are asking without providing more information about what your dataframe looks like. Can you please provide a printout `print(population)` and `print(states)` in the question description? The idea is to get an answer for yourself, but for also for everyone else. Also please edit the question title to be specific so people can find it in the future.

Comment: @OrangeSherbet you might look at tchainzzz to help you clarify it

Comment: @user11718947 You can edit the question yourself, since you know the question better than anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I randomly generated a 1000 row DataFrame with random state and population pairs: like so:

```
import random
import pandas as pd

states = ['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DC', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS',
 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR',
 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['states','pop'])

for i in range(1000):
    curr_state = states[random.randint(0, len(states)-1)]
    rand_pop = random.randint(0, 100)
    df[loc] = [curr_state, rand_pop]
```

After that, with some experimentation, I found that this absolutely monstrous chain of groupings and aggregations will get you what you want:

```
df.groupby('states').apply(pd.DataFrame.nlargest, 3, columns='pop').groupby('states').sum().reset_index()
```

Let's break this down. Basically, two aggregations are required, hence the two calls to `pd.DataFrame.groupby`:

1. We need to get the top three rows within each group of states.
2. We need to get the sum of those top three rows state by state.

`df.groupby('states').apply(pd.DataFrame.nlargest, 3, columns='pop')` gets the top three rows of each state group. We use `.apply()` instead of `.nlargest()` directly because the former works for groupby objects, and the latter doesn't. Note how parameter `columns` is passed as a keyword-argument within the call to `.apply()` so that `.nlargest()` receives its two required arguments.

Now that we have the three largest rows corresponding to each state, we aggregate and sum: `.groupby('states').sum()`. Voila!

And `.reset_index()` realigns the DataFrame, as always.

Hope this version is more suited to your needs!

Comment: This would be actually very helpful, but the thing is I simplified my data to ask here more easily.
The original data acctualy had a lot of population values for each country, and I had to take the three biggest ones, so what I did was
population.groupby(states).nlargest(3)
and the problem is that if I ask a sum right after that, I get the sum of the entire serie, not a serie with the sum by state.

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunately I can't access the coursera link you put up for some reason, but let me think with this info in mind.

Comment: I believe you will get in this link:  [Link](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-data-analysis/home/week/2)  It's the assignment 2 in the end of the page.

Comment: @user11718947 Updated my answer to reflect what we discussed.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped a lot. I'm new to pandas and am not used to most methods in there, so this huge expression will help me a lot if I dive into it

Comment: Glad it's helpful. Feel free to ask more follow up questions; I've tried to explain it step by step.